# Cron Job to import

Tags: magento, cron

Our magento store is connected to Cybertill Connector to import products and categories.

I was checking if there is any possibility to schedule a daily task to import products automatically via setting up cron in cpanel?

I have saved a link which is running when I click to import products (Admin>>connector>>product import) from magento admin http://mystorename.com/index.php/admin/connector/pullproducts/key/4c58ba58a5gt986cv/

I will appreciate if someone provide me proper steps to schedule a cron.
Sorry, I am new to magento and php if I missed anything or you want to ask something please let me know.

Thanks
Manish

Comment: Welcome to SO.  To improve your question, edit it to include details of what you've tried so far, and what the outcome was.

Answer (score 0):

The link which you mentioned is not the link which can be used in the cron jobs.

You should give the path to `cron.php` file with is in your Megento installation to run the cron jobs.

And here are the links to setup the cron job in cPanel. Refer these and try to create.

```
http://docs.klaviyo.com/article/172-set-up-magento-cron-job

http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8012/cron-job-command-in-cpanel

https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Cron+Jobs#CronJobs-Addacronemail
```